# can I save big JSON object directly to sqlite databse

Tags: android, json, database, string, sqlite

how can I save JSON object into sqlite database. Which is the best data type   to save JSON object in sqlite? Now I am using String data type to save JSON data.

Comment: *can I save big JSON object directly to sqlite databse* - what stopped you? ... but the more important thing is: what for? why not just store it as simple file ...

Comment: I know that a file can hold it too,but for easy access sqlite database is better. isn't it?

Comment: *for easy access sqlite database is better,isn't it?* ... of course not ... json is simple string ... storing it in file is easier than db (and obviously take less CPU and IO usage)

Comment: it is not just one JSON object there are too many. how can I store it in one file ? if I use a sqlite table I can save many objects and i can access it easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it in the TEXT/VARCHAR format. JSON is nothing but textual representation of Data.

***Write to DB***

```
String data = jsonObject.toString();
//save data to db
```

***Read from DB***

```
String data = //read from db
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific type for `JSONObject`.

All you can do is make `String` from your `JSONObject` and write it to database using:

```
String myString = myJsonObject.toString();
//make DB insert here
```

Then when needed, just read it:

```
String myString = /* read from DB here */
JSONObject myjsonObject = new JSONObject(myString);
```

Type for column should be `TEXT` - [SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)